# Как преобразовать string в массив объектов?

Tags: javascript, json, django

Здравствуйте. Имеется строка, полученная в результате сериализации JSON.

```
[{"input_name": "\u0427\u0443\u0436\u043e\u0439: \u0417\u0430\u0432\u0435\u0442", "input_slug": "alien"}, {"input_name": "\u0412\u0430\u043b\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0430\u043d \u0438 \u0433\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434 \u0442\u044b\u0441\u044f\u0447\u0438 \u043f\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0435\u0442", "input_slug": "valerian"}, {"input_name": "\u041b\u0435\u043e\u043d", "input_slug": "leon"}, {"input_name": "\u041c\u0435\u0447 \u043a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u043b\u044f \u0410\u0440\u0442\u0443\u0440\u0430", "input_slug": "king-arthur-legend-of-the-sword"}]
```

Как средствами javascript эту строку преобразовать в массив объектов? Используя метод ниже, у меня создается массив только с одним элементом, это с той же строкой.

```
var xr = JSON.parse("[" + x + "]")
```

Заранее благодарю :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var stroka = '[{"input_name": "\u0427\u0443\u0436\u043e\u0439: \u0417\u0430\u0432\u0435\u0442", "input_slug": "alien"}, {"input_name": "\u0412\u0430\u043b\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0430\u043d \u0438 \u0433\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434 \u0442\u044b\u0441\u044f\u0447\u0438 \u043f\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0435\u0442", "input_slug": "valerian"}, {"input_name": "\u041b\u0435\u043e\u043d", "input_slug": "leon"}, {"input_name": "\u041c\u0435\u0447 \u043a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u043b\u044f \u0410\u0440\u0442\u0443\u0440\u0430", "input_slug": "king-arthur-legend-of-the-sword"}]';
var obj = JSON.parse(stroka);

console.log(obj[2]);
console.log(obj[3].input_name);
```

`obj` - массив из 4х элементов, у каждого из которых есть свойства `input_name` и `input_slug`.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте

```js
var arr = JSON.stringify([{"input_name": "\u0427\u0443\u0436\u043e\u0439: \u0417\u0430\u0432\u0435\u0442", "input_slug": "alien"}, {"input_name": "\u0412\u0430\u043b\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0430\u043d \u0438 \u0433\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434 \u0442\u044b\u0441\u044f\u0447\u0438 \u043f\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0435\u0442", "input_slug": "valerian"}, {"input_name": "\u041b\u0435\u043e\u043d", "input_slug": "leon"}, {"input_name": "\u041c\u0435\u0447 \u043a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u043b\u044f \u0410\u0440\u0442\u0443\u0440\u0430", "input_slug": "king-arthur-legend-of-the-sword"}]);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Попробовал, но результат практически тот же. Например, обращаясь к какому либо элементу массива, выводится один символ. А хотелось бы выводить отдельный объект.

Comment: Так у вас там массив объектов, выводите согласно индексу массива нужный вам объект, в чем проблема?